# Ultra simple circuit (2 Resistor, 1 Voltage, 1 Current): Kirchhoffs Laws don't give the solution; Superposition, but how?

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws, superposition

I am doing a course on Coursera "Intro to electronics" as electronics always was my weak point.

Now we discuss npn transistors and I have simplified circuit  diagram (see below) where I am supposed to solve for VB. I am feeling really embarrassed to ask this but I want to understand this...

Given are
Rb1=15000, Rb2=82000, Vcc=15 and IB=40 mA

My idea was to to a KVL and KCL and I came up with these equations:
$$
V_{cc} - I_{b2}R_{b2}-I_{b1}R_{b1}=0 \\
I_{b2} - I_{b1}=I_{b} \\
and \\ V_{b}=V_{cc} - I_{b2}R_{b2}
$$

and this becomes

$$
I_{b2}R_{b2} + I_{b1}R_{b1}=V_{cc} \\
- I_{b1}+I_{b2}=I_{b}
$$
$$
\pmatrix{
R_{b2} & R_{b1} \cr
- 1 & 1}\pmatrix{I_{b1} \cr  I_{b2}} = \pmatrix{15 \cr  0.04}
$$

When I solve this for IB1, IB2 I get 0.04 mA and 15 mA. This gives me VB = VCC-IB2*RB2 = 14.5055 V

... which incorrect!! :-(

The solution's hint is to use superposition.

My two question:
1. What's wrong with my solution way?
2. How do I go about with a superposition?

EDIT:
ad 2:
after some more thinking: can superposition in this case mean that I

a) have one circuit without IB.

AND

b) one circuit with both voltage set to ground. Thus I get RB1 and RB2 in parallel?

[image]

Comment: You might want to work on your title, its rather meaningless

Comment: Yes. That's right. Do you have a good suggestion since I don't have a clue on how title this simple problem... :-(

Comment: Ok. I changed it. Hope this has sufficient meaning. Thanks.

Comment: "1 Voltage, 1 Current" isn't a circuit. Can you try once more to clear up the title? Also, please start early on with the schematic in your question. People are differnt, but I look at any schematic first and then read the question.

Comment: I am really sorry. I tried my best to find a good title for this problem. And thanks for the hint with the schematic.

Comment: Your matrix equation does not correspond with the simultaneous equations. If you're working a solution from the matrix equation, it's wrong.

Comment: Thanks. Yes. I did the Latex wrong. Unfortunately and funny enough the matrix I used for calculation was right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your KVL looks like this:
$$ 
I_{b2}*R_{b2} + I_{b1}*R_{b1}=V_{cc} \\
- I_{b1}+I_{b2}=I_{b}
$$

And if we plug the numbers into WolframAlpha

[http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=15+%3D+X2*82+%2B+X1*15,+X2+-+X1+%3D%3D+40](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=15%20%3D%20X2*82%20%2B%20X1*15,%20X2%20-%20X1%20%3D%3D%2040)

We get

\$I_{b1} = -33.66mA\$ and \$I_{B2} = 6.34mA\$ and \$Vb = 15V - 82k\Omega \cdot 6.34mA = - 504.8V \$

Now we can try the superposition

First I remove the current source, so we are left with this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsz4oU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The voltage divider output voltage is :

$$V_B' = Vcc*\frac{R_1}{R_2 + R1} = 2.319V$$

Next, we are short-out the voltage source so we are left with this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2falV2U.png)</sup>

Therefore \$V_B'' = - R_1||R_2 * I_B = -507.21V\$

And finally

$$V_B = V_B'+V_B'' = 2.319V + (-507.21V) = -504.8V$$

And we are done.

As you can see there is something wrong with your equivalent circuit.

I suspect that the \$I_B\$ (base current) is equal to \$40\mu A\$ (not \$40mA\$) and in this case \$V_b = 1.812V\$ seems reasonable.

Try to show us the original circuit.

Comment: One question: why −R1||R2∗IB? Especially the "-"?

Comment: And yes you are right. They seemed to mix up milli and micro.

Comment: @AndreasK. I put a "minus sign" because of the Ib current direction through resistors.  The Ib current is flowing from lower to the upper part of a resistor.  So the positive voltage is at the bottom and negative at the top of a resistor (current flow from "+" to "-").  Do you get it?